# Return a list of vegans

Tags: python-3.x

```
def vegan(something):

    list of Foods is returned  
   data = []
   for line in something:
       if line.is_vegan == True:
        data.append(line)
   return data
```

How can I make this into a recursive function, anything i try just makes it worse, this is the older function.

Comment: the usualy way of recursing a loop is to make your function handle the first parameter, and return that plus a call to the same function with the rest of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple version could be:

```
def veggies(foods):
  if not foods:
    return []
  if foods[0].is_vegetarian:
    return [foods[0]] + veggies(foods[1:])
  return veggies(foods[1:])
```

Basically you treat the first element, then pass the rest to the next call of the function, until there is no element.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand it much better now.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
veggie= [] 
counter = 0
def foodie(counter, foods):
    if counter < len(foods):
        if foods[counter].split("|")[2] == 'True':
            veggie.append(foods[counter])
        counter = counter + 1
        foodie(counter, foods)
    else:
        return; 

foodie(foods)
```

Thanks,

Comment: does not work. (hint: what type is `foods[counter].split("|")[1]` returning?)

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks for notifying it... this is untested code... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

```
f = open("foods.txt",'r')

def doStuff(f):
    line = f.readline()
    if line: # While there are lines to read, readline
        if "True" in line:
            print(line)
            # Do formatting and storing into object here
        doStuff(f)

doStuff(f)
```